# Covariate Shift Detection - Meaningful vs Significant?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, covariate-shift

I have a high-dimensional dataset (150 variables) with many observations (500k). I would like to get an intuition whether covariate shift is present over time.

I divided the dataset into two sets (early and late period). Just to get a rough first idea whether dataset shift is present, I used the maximum-mean-discrepancy test (MMD). Due to the computational time, I first started with a small random sample of 1000 points of each two datasets. However, the more observations I add for the test, the higher the significance (I know statistics - so yes this makes sense). This makes me doubt the meaningfulness of tests like MMD. Do tests like MMD make sense for datasets with many observations? In any dataset there will be small differences in the means (we are living in the real world - nothing is perfect), so with enough data any such difference will turn out to be signicant. Is there a test for covariate shift that is independent of dataset size?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say so you have $D_1=\{X_{tr},y_{tr}\}\sim P(X,Y)$ and $D_2=\{X_{ood}\}\sim Q(X,Y)$, where $P\neq Q$. If this is your situation, then in theory it's impossible to estimate model performance on $Q$. If can be than the distance between P(X) and Q(X) is very big, but does not necessarily imply that the performance will drop.

You need either to characterize the type of shift, have a causal graph, or some labeled OOD data $Q(Y)$

If you want to measure how much did the model changed, being very biased, I will suggest my own work:

- Explanation Shift: How did the distribution shift affect the model? https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.08081.pdf
- Whose implementation you can check on the skshift python package https://skshift.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In the related work section, you can find other approaches.
Would love some feedback to see if it works for your case